# "Scipy not supported!" while importing tflearn

Tags: python, scipy, tflearn

I am using Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10 and started learning tflearn (and TensorFlow). After installing both of them, I tried running `python2.7`, and then import `tflearn`, but it gives "Scipy not supported!". Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Well, we don't know if and how you installed scipy. Scipy-install on windows can be super hard. I recommend using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which is also recommend by the scipy-devs.

Comment: I eventually managed to install Scipy. Really hard to install it because the ubuntu subsystem lacks a lot of prerequisites. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got here the solution: [Scipy installed but Tflearn says Scipy not supported (win7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318495/scipy-installed-but-tflearn-says-scipy-not-supported-win7).

You have to install "numpy+mkl" (not only "numpy").