# Scipy installed but Tflearn says Scipy not supported (win7)

Tags: scipy, tensorflow, tflearn

I am using Windows 7 and tflearn (version 0.2.2, tensorflow version 0.12.1, python 3.5)and I have scipy manually installed from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ 
When I am running a tflearn code there is always the error message “scipy not supported”.

The code is running fine so far, if I don’t need scipy depending things.
When I use tflearn.data_preprocessing.ImageAugementation  that needs scipy, it gives me  a NameError: name ‘scipy’not defined.
I checked the script and it tries to import scipy.ndimage.
I have no idea, what is causing this error, scipy is installed, but tflearn can’t find it somehow…

Comment: What happens when you try to import `scipy` directly from the python prompt?

Comment: Thank you for that question! I get an ImportError: cannot import name ‘NUMPY_MKL’. I thought numpy would be enough, but in fact numpy+mkl is needed. That solved my problem, thanks a lot!